# KnockoutJS - Using data from a table in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm relatively new to knockout and I've been researching my topic for hours to no avail, so I finally find myself actually asking a question on SO that I *don't think* has been asked.

Anyway, I'm coding a basic one-page app that pulls data from the server via AJAX (done), displays a table of those records (working, but perhaps not done), and enables the user to edit the records from the table in a form on a jQueryUI dialog, preferably without loading more data from the server, as all needed data is currently in the table (this is where I'm messed up,) and then ultimately post just the one record back to the server. As a bonus, I'm hoping to make the form update the content in the table too so that it doesn't need to be reloaded.

My basic viewmodel. I also have some binding code for sorting the columns by clicking on the headers that I've left out as it's irrelevant to the question

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.records = ko.observableArray(ajaxRecords); //ajaxRecords is a JSON object from the server

    /*
        THIS SECTION MOVED BELOW FOR EXPLANATION
                                                  */

}
```

I've been able to get data into the form by using a new viewModel that's passed the object from a click function bind on each row:

```
    self.switchDataToForm = function(clickedItem) {
        ko.applyBindings(new FormViewModel(clickedItem), document.getElementById('detailsPage'));
    }
```

But I just feel like that's a bad way of doing things and this should all somehow be achievable through one ViewModel.

I'm interested to see what people say about this. It may be incredibly obvious for some, but I'm just having a hard time wrapping my head around the knockout way of thinking. If this were a jQuery task, it would have been done hours ago, but with quite a bit more markup. I'm really excited about what Knockout JS has to offer the JS dev scene and I want to start using it in practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.records = ko.observableArray(ajaxRecords); //ajaxRecords is a JSON array from the server

    self.form = ko.observable();

    self.switchDataToForm = function(clickedItem) {
        self.form(new FormViewModel(clickedItem));
    }

    /* another data goes here */
}

function FormViewModel(item) {
    var self = this;
    self.someProp = ko.observable(item.someProperty);

    /* another observables goes here */
}
```

And html:

```
<form id="detailsPage" data-bind="with: form">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: someProp" />
    ... 
</form>
```

You can see how it works in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ivan_Srb/MKB8W/2/

Comment: Thanks, that helps. What would you suggest for the save/update procedure? I'd assume I'd probably .toJSON the form and send it back with AJAX (correct me if wrong), but then what might be the best way to update the table with the changed info?

Comment: You could add to AppViewModel something like this: `self.sendFormToServer = function() { $.post("<some url>", ko.mapping.toJS(self.form()), <callback>) }` and callback can be looked like `function(data) { self.records(data) }`.

Comment: Also, you could use `$.ajax` instead of `$.post` to configurate your request more specifically. And instead of `self.records(data)` in callback you can write all what you want to update your viewModel by response data.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that callback would update the entire records array with a response from the server? I'm hoping to avoid returning the entire dataset and just update the one row I'm working with. The problem I have with doing that, and it may be because of the approach I've chosen, is that I don't think I can elegantly find the row I'm working on, as I only pulled it out of the array through the click binding's first passed parameter.

Comment: Your could look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ivan_Srb/MKB8W/3/ how to update viewModel by form data instead of server responce. But it is not better way to do it. In your case will be better to store `records` objects as observables (like a `form`) and update existing record instead of `remove` and `push`.

Comment: OK, so I should create observables for each row instead of just using one observableArray? Makes enough sense. Thanks for the advice. Nice fiddle too, it lines up great with what I thought you were saying and what I want to accomplish. Thanks again!

Comment: Refactored fiddle with observables records: http://jsfiddle.net/Ivan_Srb/MKB8W/5/. You should create new object (can not use `self.editRecord = function(clickedItem) { self.editedRecord(clickedItem); }`) for prevent automatically table row updating during text box editing.

Comment: My app is really coming together now thanks to your help. I'm only running into one more problem and maybe you'd know why...
As the data for both the table and the form is the same, I chose to use the RecordViewModel for creating observables in both sections. The initialization of the table is done by utils.arrayMap, and the form init is done with the editRecord function you suggested. My problem comes in when I try to use some computed observables in the RecordViewModel. They work and display inside the table, but when I try to show them in the form div, it only shows "function c() ... etc."

Comment: It will be better if you show me your code. You could do it with fiddle or send me screenshot.

Comment: OK, I got things working better than my last message. The only remaining problem is that the data in the form doesn't seem to be observed, even though I would think it should based on my code. The table updates properly, but the editedRecord observable doesn't seem to actually pick up on the values of the form fields it's supposedly observing. I trimmed down my code a lot for simplicity, and this fiddle works/doesn't work exactly like my full scale app...  http://jsfiddle.net/thedealmaster/t8kfV/

Comment: You could use `data-bind="value: name"` instead of `data-bind="value: name()"` and etc. Because of `()` invokes function and return result. I've forked and changed your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ivan_Srb/ZAnXj/.

Comment: Such a simple change! Thank you again, I've got substantially more done on the app now that those problems are resolved.